# Cannot Hook Category Name, and return the else statement

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks

I made a function getCategoryNameById to get and match the id of the product and I pass the function as props in the other component to use it but  when it's render a else statement which is a "none" string.

Example Data
**Product Dummy Data**

```
        {
        id: 4,
        name: "ByProgrammers Sushi",
        rating: 4.9,
        categories: [1],
        priceRating: expensive,
        photo: images.japanese_restaurant,
        duration: "10 - 15 min",
        location: {
            latitude: 1.5578068150528928,
            longitude: 110.35482523764315,
        },
        courier: {
            avatar: images.avatar_4,
            name: "Ahmad"
        },
        menu: [
            {
                menuId: 9,
                name: "Sushi sets",
                photo: images.sushi,
                description: "Fresh salmon, sushi rice, fresh juicy avocado",
                calories: 100,
                price: 50
            }
        ]
    },
```

**Dummy Category Data**

```
const categoryData = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Rice",
        icon: icons.rice_bowl,
    },
```

**The State**

```
const [categories, setCategories] = useState(categoryData)
const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState(null)
const [restaurants, setRestaurants] = useState(restaurantData)
const [currentLocation, setCurrentLocation] = useState(initialCurrentLocation)
```

**The Function**

```
    function getCategoryNameById(id) {
    let category = categories.filter(a => a.id == id)

    if(category.length > 0)
        return category[0].name
    return "none"

}
```

**Home Component**

```
    return (
    <HomeComponentContext.Provider value={{
        selectedCategory
    }}>
    <SafeAreaView>
        <Top name={currentLocation.streetName}/>
        <Categories
            item={categories}
            funct={onSelectedCategory}
            selectcat={selectedCategory}
            />
        <Product 
            products={restaurants}
            function={getCategoryNameById}
            cate = {categories}
        />
    </SafeAreaView>
    </HomeComponentContext.Provider>
)
```

**the Usage of the Function in the Product Component**

```
                    {
                    props.cate.map((categoryId) => {
                        return(
                            <View 
                            key={categoryId}
                            style={{
                                flexDirection:'row'
                            }}
                            >
                                <Text style={{ ...FONTS.body3 }}>
                                    {props.function(categoryId)}
                                </Text>
                                <Text>.</Text>
                            </View>
                        )
                    })
                }
```

Comment: Did you check the value of `id` passed to `getCategoryNameById` function?

Comment: @dothuan i didn't, does it need to log to test?

Comment: I think you should log to find where the problem comes from.

Comment: add logs in `getCategoryNameById` function to find out more about the issue.

Comment: @GulamHussain, is there a debugger or where to find the logs in android? I am currently using linux

Comment: @Dave i don't know about that. Sorry